# Force hostname for request

Tags: iis7, iis, apache2, httpd, proxy

I have a web server running Apache HTTPD 2.2 serving as a reverse proxy for my IIS 7.5 server.
This worked fine, until I wanted to use OpenID (using DotNetOpenAuth). Since DotNetOpenAuth throws an exception if I try using any realm other than the domain. To fix that I want to set the hostname server-sided (either on the reverse proxy or on the IIS server).
I was able to do that when using HTTPD as the back-end but I haven't found the configuration directive for IIS.

Comment: This would be a configuration issue of either Apache or IIS, you might want to consider asking it on Server Fault instead.

Comment: @Jack true, but the FAQ for Server Fault explicitly says that it is not the correct place for questions about `Running servers at home for personal use`

Answer (score 1):

Open IIS7 manager and on the right hand size select `Bindings`. Here you can set a host header to your site. Don't forget this name must be resolved to the IP address of the machine hosting the web site. You can do that in you DNS server. If you don't have any DNS server you can set the IP address in hosts file in `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc`.